# Is it possible to transfer contents in a C# .NET DataTable from memory to a remote file endpoint like SFTP?

Tags: c#, .net, datatable, sftp

Currently we have C# .NET Framework 4.x app that exports data from a local database into a `DataTable` in memory, then writes it to a local TSV file. Then, the TSV file is zipped and uploaded to a remote https file object storage (*OpenStack/Rackspace Cloud Files* - similar to *Amazon S3*).

The plan is to enhance this process so that we can skip the "write to local TSV and zip" steps and instead stream or pipe out the in memory `DataTable` to a new remote file destination which will be a *SFTP* server (unless we find a better protocol/storage alternative that suits this particular detail of streaming/piping from memory) without first writing to a local file system.

Any thoughts on this and if there are libraries or code examples of writing out from an memory `DataTable` contents to an opened **remote** *SFTP* endpoint so that it sees it as a file upload? Or to a different remote endpoint type but still writing out the `DataTable` without first writing to the local filesystem? (could even be our current HTTPS Cloud Files or *S3* like endpoint)

Answer (score 1):

While your solutions works, it is quite inefficient memory-wise. You end up with four copies of the data in memory:

- `DataTable`
- string returned by `ConvertDataTableToTSVFormat`
- `bytes` byte array
- `MemoryStream`

Instead, you can directly write the data to the `MemoryStream`:

```
var remoteFilename = "datatable.tsv";
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    ConvertDataTableToTSVFormat(dataTable, ms);

    using (var sftpClient = new SftpClient(host, Port, username, password))
    {
        sftpClient.Connect();
        sftpClient.BufferSize = 4 * 1024;
        sftpClient.UploadFile(ms, remoteFilename);
    }
}
```

```
private static void ConvertDataTableToTSVFormat(DataTable dataTable, Stream stream)
{
    using (var writer = new StreamWriter(stream))
    {
        string sep = string.Empty;
        foreach (var col in dataTable.Columns)
        {
            writer.Write(sep);
            writer.Write(col);
            sep = "\t";
        }
        writer.Write(Environment.NewLine);

        foreach (var dr in dataTable.Rows)
        {
            sep = string.Empty;
            foreach (var column in dr.ItemArray)
            {
                writer.Write(sep);
                writer.Write("\"" + column.ToString() + "\"");
                sep = "\t";
            }
            writer.Write(Environment.NewLine);
        }
    }
}
```

---

Alternatively, you can write the data directly to SFTP upload stream:

```
using (var stream = sftpClient.Create(remoteFilename))
{
   ConvertDataTableToTSVFormat(dataTable, stream);
}
```

Though here I'm not sure if there's any performance penalty for the upload.

Answer (score 0):

Responding with an answer and example code from a first pass at this taken recently, using Renci.SshNet library:

```cs
var remoteFilename = "datatable.tsv";
var tsvContent = ConvertDataTableToTSVFormat(dataTable);

using (var sftpClient = new SftpClient(host, Port, username, password))
{
    sftpClient.Connect();
    sftpClient.BufferSize = 4 * 1024;
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(tsvContent);
        ms.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        ms.Position = 0;
        sftpClient.UploadFile(ms, remoteFilename);
    }
}

private static string ConvertDataTableToTSVFormat(DataTable dataTable)
{
    StringBuilder fileContent = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (var col in dataTable.Columns)
    {
        fileContent.Append(col.ToString() + "\t");
    }
    fileContent.Replace("\t", System.Environment.NewLine, fileContent.Length - 1, 1);
    foreach (DataRow dr in dataTable.Rows)
    {
        foreach (var column in dr.ItemArray)
        {
            fileContent.Append("\"" + column.ToString() + "\"\t");
        }
        fileContent.Replace("\t", System.Environment.NewLine, fileContent.Length - 1, 1);
    }
    return fileContent.ToString();
}
```

Comment: More efficient would be to write the data directly to the `MemoryStream`, instead of using the intermediate "string" and "byte array". Your way, you will end up with all data four times in memory.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl Can you provide an answer to outline how you would rewrite it? I definitely don't want to quadruple the memory!